# ¿Cargar archivos de carpeta y escribirlos en un archivo?

Tags: python

quisiera saber cómo es el script para que este lea todos los archivos de una carpeta y junte todas las líneas(copiarlas) en un nuevo archivo y al principio de cada línea aparezca el nombre del archivo de procedencia separado con un espacio del contenido de la línea, ejemplo:

```
archivo1 Hola este es un ejemplo
archivo1 de lo que necesito
archivo2 no puedo usar scripts dificiles
archivo3 ni complicados, ya que no me han enseñado nada dificil en particular
archivo4 ediubewfpqgf9834gr2930r
archivo5 no sé hacerlo, gracias
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías listar los archivos de un directorio con

```
import os
root_dir = "my_directorio"

files = os.listdir(root_dir)
```

Podrias iterar la lista de archivos y leer el contenido de cada archivo con

```
content  = open(file[0], “mode”).read();
```

Y podrías escribir ir escribiendo el contenido en cada ciclo de iteración con

```
final_file = open(“final.txt”,”w”)
final_file.write(file[0] + content)
```

Te dejo la tarea de unir todo en un solo snippet :)

Comment: La verdad es que no me funciona,  lo he copiado todo a un archivo python y me da error en la linea 2: import os
root_dir ="C:\Users\minombre\Desktop\archivos" -> tmb probé con el nombre de la carpeta sin mas y nada

files = os.listdir(root_dir)
content  = open(file[0], 'mode').read();
final_file = open('final.txt','w')
final_file.write(file[0] + content)

Comment: La ruta es relativa, ahi faltan varias cosas, por eso te explicaba el proceso mas que darte el snippet completo, debes iterar la lista de files, no escribir file[0] sino file[i] donde i seria el indice el archivo en la lista y asi ..., podrías añadir tu snippet completo en la pregunta asi podemos ayudarte a corregir los errores puntuales.

Comment: gracias pero sigo sin entenderlo ;P